# Potential flow around ellipse

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian, potential-theory

I stuck at the following problem:
Consider a planar incompressible potential flow (i.e., an irrotational flow) around an
elliptic profile
\begin{equation*}
  P = \lbrace (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} \leq 1 \rbrace
\end{equation*}
for $a > b > 0$ such that the stream is going into the $x$-direction ; this is described by
the following PDE for the stream function $\psi$:
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{cases}
    \Delta \psi = 0 &, \mbox{ on } \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus P, \\
    \psi = 0 &, \mbox{ on } \partial P, \\
    \psi = y &, \mbox{ on } x^2 + y^2 \to \infty.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
Now I want to find the solution of which is symmetric about $x$.
I proceeded as follows:
First we will use the Laplacian equation for ellpitic coordinates $(\xi, \eta ) \in [0, \infty) \times [0, 2\pi)$
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{cases}
    x = K \cosh \xi \cos \eta \\
    y = K \sinh \xi \sin \eta
  \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
with $K = \sqrt{a^2 - b^2}$. Using the chain rule we get
\begin{equation*}
  \Delta \psi(\xi, \eta) = \frac{1}{K^2(\sinh^2 \xi + \sin^2 \eta)}(\partial^2_{\xi} + \partial^2_{\eta})\psi(\xi, \eta).
\end{equation*}
Using separation of variables $\psi(\xi, \eta) = u(\xi)v(\eta)$ we get
\begin{align*}
  \frac{1}{K^2(\sinh^2 \xi + \sin^2 \eta)}(\partial^2_{\xi} + \partial^2_{\eta})\psi(\xi, \eta) &= 0 \\
  & \implies (\partial^2_{\xi} + \partial^2_{\eta})u(\xi)v(\eta) = 0 \\
  &\implies u''(\xi)v(\eta) + u(\xi)v''(\eta) = 0 \\
  &\implies u''(\xi) v(\eta) = - u(\xi)v''(\eta) \\
  &\implies \frac{u''}{u}(\xi) = \alpha = -\frac{v''}{v}(\eta).
\end{align*}
Now both sides depend on different variables therefore they are constant $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and
we get
\begin{align*}
  u'' &= \alpha u, \\
  v'' &= -\alpha v.
\end{align*}
which gives the solutions
\begin{align*}
   u_{\alpha}(\xi) &= A e^{\sqrt{\alpha}\xi} + B e^{-\sqrt{\alpha} \xi} \\
  v_{\alpha}(\eta) &= C \cos(\sqrt{\alpha} \eta) + D \sin(\sqrt{\alpha} \eta).
\end{align*}
where $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}$ for the continuity of the solution.
Now $\psi = 0$ on $\partial P$ or if $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$ which gives
since the $u$ coordinate lines prescribe ellipses and the $v$ hyperboles
\begin{align*}
  \frac{K^2 \cosh^2 \xi \cos^2 \eta}{a^2} + \frac{K^2 \sinh^2 \xi \sin^2 \eta}{b^2} &= 1 \\
  &\implies b^2 \cosh^2 \xi \cos^2 \eta + a^2 \sinh^2 \xi \sin^2 \eta = \frac{a^2 b^2}{K^2} \\
  &\implies b^2 (1 + \sinh^2 \xi) \cos^2 \eta + a^2 \sinh^2 \xi \sin^2 \eta = \frac{a^2 b^2}{K^2} \\
  &\implies b^2 \cos^2 \eta + \sinh^2 \xi \left( a^2 \sin^2 \eta + b^2 \cos^2 \eta \right) = \frac{a^2 b^2}{K^2} \\
  &\implies \sinh^2 \xi = \frac{\frac{ a^2 b^2  }{K^2} - b^2 \cos^2 \eta}{a^2 \sin^2 \eta + b^2 \cos^2 \eta} \\
  &\implies \sinh^2 \xi = b^2 \frac{a^2 - K^2 \cos^2 \eta }{K^2(a^2 \sin^2 \eta + b^2 \cos^2 \eta)} \\
  &\implies \sinh \xi = b \sqrt{  \frac{a^2 - K^2 \cos^2 \eta }{K^2(a^2 \sin^2 \eta + b^2 \cos^2 \eta)}  } \\
  &\implies \xi_0 = \mbox{arsinh} \left( b \sqrt{  \frac{a^2 - K^2 \cos^2 \eta }{K^2(a^2 \sin^2 \eta + b^2 \cos^2 \eta)}  } \right)
\end{align*}
for $\eta \in [0, 2\pi)$. Also
\begin{align*}
  x^2 + y^2 &= K^2 \left( \cosh^2 \xi \cos^2 \eta + \sinh^2 \xi \sin^2 \eta \right) \\
  &= K^2 \left( \cos^2 \eta + \sinh^2 \xi (\cos^2 \eta + \sin^2 \eta) \right) \\
  &= K^2 \left( \cos^2 \eta + \sinh^2 \xi \right) \\
  &= K^2 \left( 1 - \sin^2 \eta + \sinh^2 \xi \right) \\
  &= K^2 \left(1 + \sinh^2 \xi - \sin^2 \eta  \right) \\
  &= K^2 \left( \cosh^2 \xi - \sin^2 \eta \right)
\end{align*}
which diverges to $+\infty$ if $\xi \to +\infty$ or $\xi \to -\infty$ and $\eta \in [0, 2\pi )$. But we only
look at $\xi \to +\infty$ since $\xi \in [0, \infty)$.Then we have
\begin{equation*}
  \psi(\xi, \eta) = u_{\alpha}(\xi)v_{\alpha}(\eta) \approx K \sinh \xi \sin \eta = K \frac{1}{2} e^{\xi} \sin \eta
\end{equation*}
We also have that $\xi = \xi_0$ describes the ellipse $P$ in
elliptic coordinates with $\eta \in [0, 2\pi)$
\begin{equation*}
  \psi(\xi_0, \eta) = u_{\alpha}(\xi_0) v_{\alpha}(\eta) = 0.
\end{equation*}
Somehow the second boundary condition would lead to the solution being trivial. Im not sure where I did make a mistake or why my way of solving this is wrong.
Edit: From the above boundary condition and the x-axis symmetrie we can write the solution as a sum for $\alpha $ in $\mathbb{N}$ and solve $A,B$ and $D$ from the boundary conditions. The symmetrie gives $C = 0$ and only one summand $\alpha = 1$ from the condition in the farfield is needed. Then one gets a solution for $\psi$.

Comment: If I interpret correctly that $\mathbf{v}=\operatorname{grad}\psi,$ then I don't understand why $\psi=0$ on $\partial P.$ I would expect instead $\mathbf{v}$ tangent to $\partial P$, i.e. $\mathbf{v}\cdot\operatorname{grad}f = 0,$ where $f(x,y)=0$ is the cartesian equation of $\partial P.$

Comment: Worth mentioning that a conformal map which takes the boundary of the ellipse to the  boundary of a circle simplifies things